# Mailbox is always read-only in Mutt

Tags: linux, email, permissions, mutt

I just installed Mutt and I'm currently unable to delete mail from my mailbox. Mutt will give a message saying it is unable to do this because the mailbox is ready-only. I can send and receive messages fine.

I searched for a solution and the advice is to set group id for the file mutt_dotlock. Following the instructions I ran the command:

```
ls -lF `which mutt` `which mutt_dotlock`
```

which gave the following result:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    22 May  6 12:36 /usr/bin/mutt -> /etc/alternatives/mutt*
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root mail 10600 Aug 24  2012 /usr/bin/mutt_dotlock*
```

I then ran sudo chmod g+s /usr/bin/mutt_dotlock but the mailbox is still read-only. Permissions for mutt-dotlock are now:

```
-rwxrwsr-x 1 root mail 10600 Aug 24  2012 /usr/bin/mutt_dotlock
```

Next I checked the permissions on my mail file in /var/mail using ls -l /var/mail/steve:

```
-rw------- 1 steve vmail 10457 Aug 11 19:29 steve
```

So, following the advice on the web I ran chmod 700 on /var/mail/steve and the permissions are currently:

```
-rwx------ 1 steve   vmail 10457 Aug 11 19:29 steve
```

This still did not allow me to delete email in Mutt. Finally, someone suggested running chmod 2775 on /usr/bin/mutt_dotlock, which I did and the permissions are now:

```
-rwxrwsr-x 1 root mail 10600 Aug 24  2012 /usr/bin/mutt_dotlock
```

I still can't delete mail and I don't know where to go from here. The permissions all look OK. Is there a way to verify that the dot lock is being created in /var/mail? This is a basic mail gateway that I set up on a Debian server using Postfix with unix system accounts. No POP3 or imap and I'd rather not bother.

I'm not very familiar with Mutt but I would like to keep using it as a way to check my mail from the command line but eventually will need to delete messages. :) I know Mutt is still in use so if anyone has seen this before or can offer any advice I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: What does `ls -ld /var/mail` show? If the group on that directory matches the group on your mailbox the `mutt_dotlock` command will actually need to be changed to belong to the `vmail` group.

Comment: Good catch. ls -ld /var/mail is showing: drwxrwsr-x 2 vmail vmail 4096 Aug 11 19:29 /var/mail. I guess chown root:vmail /usr/bin/mutt_dotlock eh?

Comment: Yes, I believe that would fix it.

Comment: No, I thought it would as well but same problem. I also verified that I can delete mail using system mail command but not Mutt.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make yourself belong to the vmail group.

The directory permission requires user running to be in that group in order to modify file in `/var/mail directory`.  There should be no permission change required for any program

Try running (if in Unix/Linux)

```
usermod -a -G vmail your_user_name
```

Comment: If you're running on mac OSX (Darwin), the user group you need to add yourself to is `mail` ... there's no usermod in Darwin, but you can use `dseditgroup` to accomplish the same thing: `dseditgroup -o edit -u [username] -p -a [username] -t user mail`. The first username needs to be an admin.

Comment: Once you've done this, I had to open a new shell (on Mac OS X)

Comment: I had this problem on Debian Bookworm (current testing version), and adding my username to the 'mail' group solved the problem as noted.

Comment: On Linux one can use newgrp to log into the new group without logging out