# Mutt cannot delete messages

Tags: linux, email, mutt

Running mutt on AWS EC2 instance with Amazon Linux, I cannot delete any messages,
running mutt either as a regular user or as root for root mailbox.

When quitting, following 'Purge deleted messages'
I get thrown into an empty 'No mailbox' mailbox with message
'Fatal error! Could not reopen mailbox!"

Tried to fix using suggestions in thread 'Mailbox is always read-only in Mutt'
[Mailbox is always read-only in Mutt](https://superuser.com/questions/631015/mailbox-is-always-read-only-in-mutt)
but no success.  I did note that I cannot find file
/usr/bin/mutt_dotlock mentioned in that thread on my system.
Also noticed that the problem cited there never got solved :-(

Have been a decades long user of mutt elsewhere, but problems on EC2

Comment: Sure sounds like permissions. Check ~/.muttrc and $MAIL

Comment: Forgot to say that /var/spool/mail/admin has rw permission for both user and group='mail'.  Just to do something, changed ~/.muttrc group to 'mail' with rw permission, but no change.

Comment: Do you need to add your user to group mail?

Comment: No, admin is member of group.  Have to wonder if is permissions problem since mutt fails in same fashion when used by root, which should have all permissions