# mutt disallows deletion of message with error "Mailbox is read-only" in WSL

Tags: linux, email, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mutt, fetchmail

`MAIL` in `.bashrc` is set thus:

`MAIL=/var/spool/mail/Tryer && export MAIL`

`fetchmail` and `mutt` commands work fine and display any new message received. However, on trying to delete a message in `mutt`, I get an error that states: `Mailbox is read-only.`

I tried to follow the steps specified in an old question along same lines available [here](https://superuser.com/questions/631015/mailbox-is-always-read-only-in-mutt).

The output is as follows:

```
:~$ ls -ld /var/mail
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Sep 18 21:59 /var/mail
```

The solution there seemed to suggest that the user `Tryer` should be added to group `vmail`. However, the above output does not indicate any `vmail` group. It only specified the `root`.  It is not clear to me whether I should add user `Tryer` to `root` group.

Comment: What does `ls -l /var/spool/mail/Tryer` give?

Comment: There is no such file/folder `ls: cannot access '/var/spool/mail/Tryer': No such file or directory` Indeed, the folder /var/spool/mail/ is empty.

Comment: where's your mail spool file ? Give the relevant extracts of `.muttrc` then, your question mentions your  `$MAIL` being that file that doesn't exist.

Comment: @JoceNoToPutinsWarInUkraine Sorry, I ran that command when there was no mail in my inbox and that file was deleted. On running `fetchmail` again, that file does get populated and here is the output of the command you suggested:
`-rw------- 1 Tryer root 7186 Oct  9 10:28 /var/spool/mail/Tryer`